# PostgresQL window function over blocks of continuous IDs

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have a table with partially consecutive integer ids, i.e. there are blocks such as `1,2,3, 6,7,8, 10, 23,24,25,26`.

- the gap size is dynamic
- the length of the blocks is dynamic

I am breaking my head about a **simple** solution that selects from the table
and includes a column where the value corresponds to the first id of the respective block.

I.e. something like this

```
select id, first(id) over <what goes here?> first from table;
```

The result should look as following

```
| id | first |
|----|-------|
| 1  | 1     |
| 2  | 1     |
| 3  | 1     |
| 6  | 6     |
| 7  | 6     |
| 8  | 6     |
| 10 | 10    |
| 23 | 23    |
| 24 | 23    |
| 25 | 23    |
| 26 | 23    |
```

Afterwards i could use this column nicely with the `partition by` window function clause.

What I came up with so far always looked similar to this and didn't succeed:

```
WITH foo AS (
    SELECT LAG(id) OVER (ORDER BY id)  AS previous_id,
           id                          AS id,
           id - LAG(id, 1, id) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS first_in_sequence
    FROM table)
SELECT *,
       FIRST_VALUE(id) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS first
FROM foo
ORDER BY id;
```

Defining a custom postgres function would also be an acceptable solution.

Thanks for any advice,

Marti

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Postgres you can [create a custom aggregate.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createaggregate.html) Example:

```
create or replace function first_in_series_func(int[], int)
returns int[] language sql immutable
as $$ 
    select case 
        when $1[2] is distinct from $2- 1 then array[$2, $2]
        else array[$1[1], $2] end; 
$$;

create or replace function first_in_series_final(int[])
returns int language sql immutable
as $$
    select $1[1]
$$;

create aggregate first_in_series(int) (
    sfunc = first_in_series_func,
    finalfunc = first_in_series_final,
    stype = int[]
);
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=bb27e4e248ad4d10924231690cfb3ff4)

Read in the docs: [User-Defined Aggregates](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xaggr.html)

Comment: Wonderful. I accept this, because I feel its the more declarative way to solve it. It's probably also a solution that is easier to transfer to similar problems and pointed me to the respective documentation :)

Comment: The ability to create aggregate functions is one of the highlights of Postgres. I'm happy to give examples of custom aggregates because people think it's hard but actually is easier than might seem at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea how this could be done. An implicit cursor is not horribly efficient though.

```sql
create or replace function ff()
returns table (r_id integer, r_first integer)
language plpgsql as
$$
declare
  running_previous integer;
  running_id integer;
  running_first integer := null;
begin 
    for running_id in select id from _table order by id loop
        if running_previous is distinct from running_id - 1 then
            running_first := running_id;
        end if;
        r_id := running_id;
        r_first := running_first;
        running_previous := running_id;
        return next;
    end loop;
end
$$;
-- test
select * from ff() as t(id, first);
```